# Rails 3 - Status of "link_to_function" method

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In searching for a solution to a javascript problem, I saw multiple comments about `link_to_function` being deprecated in Rails 3.  However, I've been able to complete a section of my Rails-3-based project using `link_to_function`.  It works fine.

Being new Rails, my concern is that I might be using something that is not going to be supported over the long-term or could become a legacy hack.  In looking at api.rubyonrails.org, I see `link_to_function` clearly called out in the ActionView::Helpers::JavaScriptHelper module as a supported public method for Ruby on Rails v3.0.4.  No warnings or other statements about the longevity of the function.

Is there some other approach/method that I should be using instead of `link_to_function` in Rails 3?  Or is `link_to_function` fine to use?

Thanks.

Comment: Being deprecated means that it is still included, but will be removed in the near future so its use is not recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I still have a concern in that deprecation is not called out in the official docs.  Coming in from the Java and PHP community, deprecation was almost always clearly communicated in the official API docs.  Doesn't look like that is the case in the Ruby on Rails arena.  I was warned that RoR documentation tradition is weak, but the testing ethos is exceptional.  So far I'm finding that to be true.  :-)

Comment: So what's the preferred method of getting the job done? Making a class, and binding jQuery functions to it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `link_to_function` helper has been [deprecated again in 3.2.4](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5922).

The method itself is quite simply and good in some use cases when you need to call specific javascript function etc. You can easily add your own helper to achieve the same functionality. The following code was copied from Jeremy in https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5922#issuecomment-5770442

```
# /app/helpers/link_to_function_helper.rb
module LinkToFunctionHelper
  def link_to_function(name, *args, &block)
     html_options = args.extract_options!.symbolize_keys

     function = block_given? ? update_page(&block) : args[0] || ''
     onclick = "#{"#{html_options[:onclick]}; " if html_options[:onclick]}#{function}; return false;"
     href = html_options[:href] || '#'

     content_tag(:a, name, html_options.merge(:href => href, :onclick => onclick))
  end
end
```

Comment: For anyone finding this in Rails 4.1+... this is still the case -- the link_to_function method is gone!

Answer (score 15):

**[Update]**

As TomH mentions, it is [now deprecated again](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5922) in Rails 3.2.4

**[Original Answer]**

`link_to_function` is **no longer deprecated** and is **safe for use**. Details:

`link_to_function` was slated to be removed in Rails 3 (and was for a while when Rails 3 was in beta), but the function was put back in https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/d69e561. Several people wondered (aloud, in the comments of the commit) why the function was put back, when the big push in Rails 3 was for [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/), so DHH chimed in:

> This is to handle non-generic function
>   triggers explicitly in ERb when you're
>   not inclined to manually hook it up
>   through JS. The big win for UJS in
>   Rails 3 is getting rid of big swaths
>   of boilerplate code ala data-confirm
>   and data-remote. These generics are
>   auto-wired and you don't have to
>   bother with it.
>
> But for your own functions, ala
>   link_to_function "Add calendar",
>   "Calendar.add()", this is a more
>   direct, immediate way to go. If you
>   still would rather go through an
>   external JS and wire it up by hand
>   through dom:ready, have a field day.
>
> The support for UJS in Rails 3 is not
>   about being dogmatic. Just like the
>   support for REST isn't. We'll expose
>   the major value to everyone and then
>   allow for outlets where it makes
>   since. Here, it makes sense.
>
> This, btw, is not about prototype or
>   any other specific js framework.

Comment: @TomH: so, it seems that the support for unobstructive Javascript in Rails 3 *is* about being dogmatic, after all.

Answer (score 2):

While I am intending to switch everything over to unobtrusive javascript, a good intermediate step (for me), was to replace

```
link_to_function icon_tag('close.png'), '$(this).parent().hide()', :title => t('actions.close'), :class => 'close'
```

with the following:

```
link_to icon_tag('close.png'), '#', :onclick => '$(this).parent().hide()', :title => t('actions.close'), :class => 'close'
```

Very simple. Hope this helps.