# Rails 4.0 JQuery click callback not getting called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, unobtrusive-javascript

I am using rails 4.0 and I want to remove obtrusive javascript. I must be missing something, I have this link_to:

```
= link_to t('hide'),'#', :'data-hide-table'=>"#row_#{@result.id}", :class=>'hider'
```

In my model.js I have following code (I have also tried putting it inside application.js):

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hider').click(function (event) {
      console.log("fsg");
      $(this).data("hide-table").hide();
      event.preventDefault();
    });
  });
```

However, nothing is being logged into console, and of course  that I need to hide is not being hidden. Btw. everything works when I use:

```
= link_to_function t('hide'), "$('#row_#{@result.id}').hide()"
```

Comment: `link_to_function` in rails 4?????

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063246/rails-3-status-of-link-to-function-method look at it

Comment: 2 Rajarshi Das, link_to_function is deprecated and will not be supported since 4.1 and I want to remove it from my code, in my question it is mentioned just for illustration that it works using link_to_function, but thanks for your link

Comment: and btw. using :onclick, as suggested in posted link does not seem to be unobtrusive way of handling onclick event in rails

Comment: `:'data-hide-table'=>"#row_#{@result.id}"` what is it?

Comment: `= link_to t('hide'),'#',  :onclick => "$('#row_#{@result.id}').hide();"`...try this

Comment: :'data-hide-table'=>"#row_#{@result.id}" is the way of giving parameters for event handling using jguery (at least according to this guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#unobtrusive-javascript), and sure I could use :onclick, but it still is not unobtrusive javascript that i would like to use