# Capturing events on a web page

Tags: ruby, events, httpresponse, webrick, ruby-1.9

I am running a web page from a server using webrick. How can I capture an event from the web browser? I do not want to do it through JavaScript, but I want to get a response through webrick, and process it in ruby, perhaps using one of the `do_...` methods. If JavaScript is minimally needed, that is okay. I do not want to redirect to a different page.
I do not know what to put in the value for an event (like `onclick`).

```
<input type=button onclick="..." value="Press Me">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling, with the help of [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp), I seem to have gotten close to what I wanted:

*xxx.html*

```
<input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="onclick('value to pass');" />
```

*xxx.js*

```
function onclick(v){
  e=new XMLHttpRequest();
  e.open("GET", "http://localhost:3000?t=0&"+v, true);
  e.onreadystatechange=function(){if (e.readyState==4 && e.status==200){
    // some code to rewrite if necessary
  };};
  e.send();
}
```

*xxx.rb*

```
class WEBrick::HTTPServlet::AbstractServlet
  def do_GET request, response
    # some code to process the request
    response.body = a_return_string_for_rewriting
    response.status = 200
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Webrick is HTTP server in Ruby. In order to communicate with HTTP server from event handler, you'll need to write some JavaScript code. For example:

```
<input type=button onclick="javascript:send(this);" value="Press Me">
```

And then define send() function:

```
function send(event) {
   // Create Ajax request to the server
}
```

Comment: I was trying to see how I can do it other than that way.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are describing ajax. Try:

```
link_to "target", {:controller => controller, :action => method, }, :remote => true
```

from this SO answer:

[Where did link_to_function disappear to in Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250231/where-did-link-to-function-disappear-to-in-rails-3)

Edit: Sorry, I assumed Rails when you were asking for Ruby.

Comment: I am not using Rails. I am just trying to do it by myself. But if I can know how it is implemented in Rails, that can help.