# I am trying to add a block dynamically. I is giving an error saying "wrong no. of arguments"(1 for 2).

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

the partial is named new_campaign_partial.rhtml. It has just the html code for creating certain text fiels and calendar

```
 <div id="new_campaign"
 <%render :partial =>'new_campaign_partial'%>
 </div>

 <%= link_to_function "Add a campaign" do |page|
    inser_html :bottom, :new_campaign, :partial=>'new_campaign_partial'
   end%>
```

Comment: you have tagged this question as **rails-3** and [link_to_function is now gone from rails 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250231/where-did-link-to-function-disappear-to-in-rails-3)

Answer (score 0):

Change `inser_html` to `page.insert_html` Ref :- [insert_html](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/JavaScriptGenerator/GeneratorMethods.html#M002186)

```
<%= link_to_function "Add a campaign" do |page|
    page.insert_html :bottom, :new_campaign, :partial=>'new_campaign_partial'
   end %>
```